# Is $U=\{(r,0,s)\mid r^2+s^2=0, r,s\in \mathbb{R}\}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Is $U=\{(r,0,s)\mid r^2+s^2=0, r,s\in \mathbb{R}\}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

If I set $r=s=0$, then it shows the zero vector is in $U$.

For showing that U is closed under scalar multiplication and addition, I used the facts that $t(0,0,0)=(0,0,0)\in U, t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $(0,0,0)+(0,0,0)=(0,0,0)\in U$. This should be valid because $(0,0,0)$, my original vector I am choosing is in $U$. So I think $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Since the sum of two squared real numbers must be positive or $0$, and the sum of the two real numbers is $0$ in the condition of $U$, I chose $r=s=0$, because the only way to get two squared real numbers to add up to zero is if they are both zero.

Is this correct?

Comment: "I couldn't think of any other numbers" is not a proof. You need to prove it. What do you know about squares of real numbers?

Comment: Squares of real numbers must be positive or $0.$

Comment: Bingo. And the sum of two non-negative reals is $0$ when?

Comment: Only when both those real numbers are $0.$

Comment: Right. And now write that up in a nice way, and you have proved that $U = \{(0,0,0)\}$. Then all that remains is to change the $2$ from the scalar multiplication to a generic $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(To take this out of the unanswered pile...)

Yes, you are correct. The condition means that $r^2=-s^2$ and this can only occur if $r=s=0$. By the subspace test, it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Therefore $U$ is indeed a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.